# why multiple condition in python while loop are not working?

Tags: python, while-loop, multiple-conditions

I can't seem to find the problem in code...

```
user_decision = ""
while not user_decision == "yes" or not user_decision == "no":
    user_decision = input("You want to Join?: Please answer (yes/no): ")
else:
    if user_decision == "yes":
        print("test")
    else:
        print("test")
```

Thanks....

Comment: You want `and`, not `or`.

Comment: Also, `user_decision != "yes" ` is the same as `not user_decision == "yes"`, and might be easier to read

Comment: you'd be better off checking this a different way: if you have a list of possible values, the "in" operator is handy instead of trying to get the grouping of a set of tests right:  `while user_decision not in ('yes', 'no'):`

Comment: I had solved it .... I just  wanted to know what am I doing wrong in the above piece of code.... couldn't find it... so asked...Got it at the cost of 6 reps ... worth it...

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned it up a bit:

```
user_decision = ""
while  (user_decision != "yes") and (user_decision != "no"):
    user_decision = input("You want to Join?: Please answer (yes/no): ")
    if user_decision == "yes":
        print("test yes")
    else:
        print("test not yes")
```